# Oldest "Ugly" Proof

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, math-history

Recently, in math class, I learnt about the four colour theorem. Our teacher described it as quite an "ugly" proof, and I can see why. However, in the history of mathematics, this proof is quite recent, and so if this is one of the oldest "ugly" proofs, then would it be safe to say we will probably have an elegant way to prove it eventually? My question is: what is the oldest "ugly" proof? Also, is there a way of proving that something can't have an elegant proof?

Comment: Define "elegance."  (I know what it means, but if you want a proof whether a particular statement has an elegant proof, the term must be defined mathematically.)

Comment: I am not sure if this is a serious question. *Ugly* is not globally defined and hence nothing can be proven to be ugly or not ugly. As another point you want to prove that the existence of a proof implies the existence of other proofs?

Comment: I think the question is all right, but would tag it with "soft question"

Comment: But still some particular meaning of "elegant" as used in phrase "elegant proof" should be identified. Similar remark applies to  the term "ugly". For me a proof is elegant if it uses least amount of mathematical machinery and has a simple logical structure (so that the enjoyment of understanding it not limited to elite few but rather has mass appeal). Some people are more impressed by a slick proof which uses sophisticated mathematics and they would term that kind of proof as elegant.

Comment: I think that one way to refine this question to the specific kind of "ugliness" the asker might be thinking of is to ask what the first proof might have been that required checking a large number of cases individually.

Comment: I'm closing this as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

The proof of the existence of only five platonic solids is ugly, and very old:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Geometric_proof

It seems that a problem with many constrainst leads often to enumeration, and that's ugly.